# reduce string length when it has pair in java

Tags: java, string, var, charat

**here it is giving error----required variable ,found value**
**my code**
*for eg aabacc when we got any pair like aa remove it from string and the final answer is (ba).*

public class Solution {

```
// Complete the superReducedString function below.
static String superReducedString(String s) {
    String sn;
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++)
    {
        if(s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1))
        {
            sn.charAt(j)=s.charAt(i);                           
            j++;
        }
    }
    return sn;
}
```

Comment: Whats your problem? Describe it further.

Comment: eg   aabacc  when we got any pair  like aa remove it from string and the final answer is   (ba).

Comment: Strings are immutable. You can't edit them like you're trying to do here. I recommend using a `char[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since String is immutable in Java - String manipulation always generates a new String leaving the previous Strings in String Pool. [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) and [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) are mutable objects and provide methods for String manipulation

Sample working method using StringBuilder is provided below:

```
static String superReducedString(String s) {
    StringBuilder myName = new StringBuilder(s);
    int j=0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length()-1;i++) {
        if(s.charAt(i)!=s.charAt(i+1)) {
            myName.setCharAt(j, s.charAt(i));                           
            j++;
        }
    }
    return myName.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do such assignment like `sn.charAt(j)=s.charAt(i);` since `charAt()` is function that returns the result, but not a variable. You could use `StringBuilder` here:

```
static String superReducedString(String s) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.length() == i+1 || s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i + 1)) {
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

`s.length() == i+1` checks if it's the last char. In case `aabaccr` the result will be as expected `bar`

Comment: I am unable to understand the working of s. Length() ==i+1 here can u plz describe

Comment: @Sam we have a loop from `0` to `s.length()` (in case of `aabaccr` the length = `7`).  When the `s.length() == i+1` gives `true` that means we are on the index of the last char from string (this is `r`) and we should add this char to the result since there is no pair for it (there is no chars after `r`). I think it would be better for you to debug your program and you could see what happens step by step. Hope it helps!

Comment: @Sam Glad to help! If you find this useful, please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple.
you cannot delete anything from a String but you can move them to another `String` as you want.

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "abbccd", s1 = "";

        if(s.charAt(1) != s.charAt(0))
            s1 += s.charAt(0);
        if(s.charAt(s.length()-1) != s.charAt(s.length()-2))
            s1 += s.charAt(s.length()-1);

        for (int i = 1; i < s.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i - 1) && s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(i + 1))
                s1 += s.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println(s1);
    }

}
```

You create another String.
Then in a for loop iterating from `1` (NOT `0`) to `s.length()-1` (NOT `s.length()`), you check if the `s.charAt(i)` (current character) is equal to the preceding or following one. If it's not equal to any of them, you add it to the second `String` and then you print it.  We are checking both sides so that's why the loop is from `1` to `s.length()-1`, to avoid out of bounds exceptions.

**EDIT:** to check the first and last character.

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution, in case the other answers don't work for you:

```
static String superReducedString(String s) {
    char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
    String lastChar = "";
    ArrayList<String> newString = new ArrayList<>();
    for (char aChar : chars) {
        String currentChar = String.valueOf(aChar);
        if (lastChar.equals(currentChar))
            newString.remove(newString.size() - 1);
        else {
            newString.add(currentChar);
            lastChar = currentChar;
        }
    }

    AtomicReference<String> returnString = new AtomicReference<>("");
    newString.forEach(character-> returnString.set(returnString + character));
    return returnString.get();
}
```